# ReactNative - Undefined is not an object (evaluating x)

Tags: module, react-native

I'm reading through, following a tutorial online about ReactNative where it "includes" a file into the project; almost like a partial.

I get this error;

[image: Picture of an error]

My `index.ios.js` is

```
// Imports
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  AppRegistry,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View
} from 'react-native';

//var DayItem = require('./src/day-item');
import {
  DayItem
} from './src/day-item';


// Component
class Weekdays extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <Text style={styles.textStyles}>
          Days of the Week
        </Text>
        <DayItem />
      </View>
    );
  }
}

AppRegistry.registerComponent('Weekdays', () => Weekdays);
```

The `day-item` file is:

```
// Imports
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  AppRegistry,
  StyleSheet,
  Text
} from 'react'

// Component
class DayItem extends Component { 
    render() {
        return (
            <Text>
            Hello world
            </Text>
        );
    } 
}

var { NativeModules } = require('react-native');
module.exports = NativeModules.DayItem;
```

I've not done React Native before, but I'm not sure what its referring to when it claims undefined is not an object.

The idea is to include this module into my main project and present the DayItem module in one line.

I have noticed that sometimes I get errors with

`<DayItem />`

If I put it outside the `<View>`, but inside its fine.

Anyhow, I am unsure of how to get my Hello World Partial to work inside my main file.

Any help on this would be helpful.

Thanks for now

Comment: Why not `export default DayItem` and forget the `var { NativeModules } = require('react-native')` , then, `import DayItem from './src/day-item'`  ?

Comment: Sorry I've not done much ReactNative before.   Why use `module.exports = ...` ?   Because I was having real trouble using `module.export`, it appears the codebase of ReactNative has changed recently; so I found that solution on another question and I assumed it was correct

Comment: Glad you got it working :) Cheers

Comment: Thanks for the assistance; its all new to me at the moment

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There were couple of mistakes in code as pointed by Cherniv and Nader.

Another mistake was in day-item js file

```
import {
  AppRegistry,
  StyleSheet,
  Text
} from 'react';
```

should be

```
import {
  AppRegistry,
  StyleSheet,
  Text
} from 'react-native';
```

Here is the complete working code.

index.ios.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  AppRegistry,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View
} from 'react-native';

import DayItem from './src/day-item';


// Component
class Weekdays extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <Text>
          Days of the Week
        </Text>
        <DayItem />
      </View>
    );
  }
}

AppRegistry.registerComponent('Weekdays', () => Weekdays);
```

src/day-item.js

```
// Imports
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  AppRegistry,
  StyleSheet,
  Text
} from 'react-native';

// Component
class DayItem extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <Text>
            Hello world
            </Text>
        );
    }
}

export default DayItem;
```

Comment: I will give it a go.